# ContainsValue vs equals method TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, key, treemap

i wanto to print the selected key and value that arrive here from a scanner object. I tried in this way and i notice a difference:

```
    TreeMap<String, String> oldbooks = new TreeMap<String,String>();
    oldbooks.put("WaltDisney", "DonaldDuck");
    oldbooks.put("Shakespeare", "Amleto");
    oldbooksput("Dickens", "OliverTwist");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String title = in.next();
    boolean found =             oldbooks.containsValue(title);
    for(String k : oldbooks.keySet())
    {
        if(found) {
            System.out.print("The value is : "+ oldbooks.get(k)
            +" The Key is: "+ k);
        }
    }
```

I notice that in this way i obtain every keys and every values, i want the right key and the right value. If i change my if condition and i put:

```
if(title.equals(oldbooks.get(k))
```

Now it function very well. So why i can't print the specified value and key with the first solution? i know that .equals give me true and false just like containsValue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mistook the key and the value in your example code.

Comment: But why i can't print nothing in the containsValue?

Comment: because the map does not contain the title(as Value!)

Comment: btw I would iterate over `oldbooks.entrySet()`.

Comment: @dan1st the title is a String that i obtain from a scanner object. If i just put "TheManintheMoon" at the place of title, i obtain the same nothing. I try to understand what you say, title is a string not in the Map, but is the same in the if condition (title.equals(oldbook.get(k)) or i forgot somethinghs? thank you in advance

Comment: @dan1st i tried and is the same

Comment: How does your map look like? Does it have ID-Title pairs or Title-some_detail pairs? Also, what is the input you are giving? Can you give an example of the input and what is there in the map?

Comment: @dan1st no, i didn't use the object, is simple in this way:  TreeMap<String, String> oldbooks = new TreeMap<String,String>();

Comment: @ShivamPuri the input is only what you see in the question:Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String title = in.next();

Comment: What are you typing in the console as input for the scanner? And what do you expect to find in the map?

Comment: I don't see why this should return false if you are looking for the right string. Try printing title before calculating for the Boolean found. ```System.out.println(title);```. Does it have any whitespaces? Or some unexpected string value?

Comment: @ShivamPuri it return nothing, not false, i go inside the for but it dont print nothing

Comment: I'll go ahead and ask a basic question now. Do you know why you are using the Scanner input in your code? If yes, then can you tell me what input you are giving in the console to search for in the map?

Comment: @ShivamPuri my scanner variable is: DonaldDuck

Comment: This code does not produce the behavior you described. Post the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your edit, you are putting the values in a different map `archivio` and trying to search for it in a different map `oldbooks`.

Was that intentional? Or perhaps that is the problem in your code!

Below code is working fine for me;

```
    TreeMap<String, String> oldbooks = new TreeMap<>();
    oldbooks.put("WaltDisney", "DonaldDuck");
    oldbooks.put("Shakespeare", "Amleto");
    oldbooks.put("Dickens", "OliverTwist");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String title = in.next();
    boolean found = oldbooks.containsValue(title);
    for(String k : oldbooks.keySet())
    {
        if(found) {
            System.out.print("The value is: "+ oldbooks.get(k)
            +" The Key is: "+ k);
        }
    }
```

When I run this in my IDE, I simply have to type `DonaldDuck` in the console and I am getting the expected result (prints all key-value pairs).

Also, FYI, you have been printing incorrect key-values in your system.out.print statement.

The key is `k` and the value is what you get using `oldbooks.get(k)`. Not the other way around. (As pointed by @[dan1st](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10871900/dan1st) in the first comment).

Comment: @dan1st i just want the Key and the value of DonaldDuck, not all keys and values. If i try with if(title.equals(oldbooks.get(k))
i obtain the right value and key

Comment: I course it will. I understand what your questions title means now. The ```containsValue``` method will only check if the value you are looking for is there in the map. It will not give any hint to which index the value is "DonaldDuck". So that is why the code in my answer always returns key values for all indexes in the map, if ```found``` is true. The if condition you have written using ```equals``` returns true only and only when the value of that ```k``` index item is equal to the value you are looking for when iterating using for loop in the map.